# Lexer rule (regex) for TeX equation

Tags: lex

In TeX, equations are defined in between `$...$`. How can I define the lexer rule for lex, for the instance of *any number of any characters between two dollar signs*?

I tried:

```
equation  \$[^\$]*\$
```

without a success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html) if you don't want the dollar signs to be included as part of the equation:

```
%x EQN
%%
\$ { BEGIN(EQN); } /* switch to EQN start condition upon seeing $ */
<EQN>{
    \$ { BEGIN(INITIAL); } /* return to initial state upon seeing another $ */
    [^\$]* { printf(yytext); } /* match everything that isn't a $ */
}
```

Alternately instead of using `BEGIN(STATE)` you can use `yy_push_state()` and `yy_pop_state()` if you have other states defined in your lexer.

Comment: great, this can also be used to differentiate between ``$`` and ``$$``