# lexer rule, "anything but" for a multi-character string

Tags: lex

In flex, how can I define a lexer rule such as anything but `$$`. For a single character, it is defined as:

```
[^\$]
```

For `$$`, is it equal to `[^\$\$]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the single character correct, now just double it: `[^\$][^\$]`. This will accept any two characters that are not '$'. If you want to allow a single '$' then you will need to provide that as alternatives: `[^\$][^\$]|\$[^\$]|[^\$]\$`.

This will end up as a DFA eventually anyway, so there are no efficiency concerns. If you need to do this more than once, give the pattern a name so you only need to have it once.

Comment: Actually, I'm using a start condition to gobble up LaTeX equations between ``$$...$$``. So look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717920/lexer-rule-regex-for-tex-equation. I'm not looking for two characters that are both not ``$``.

Comment: Fair enough, but that wasn't the question you asked. You asked for 'anything but $$' so that was what I tried to answer.

Comment: Indeed :D. I'm opening a new question.

Comment: How about just editing this one to clarify what you intended to ask?

Comment: I think it's better to leave it for future reference. Besides, too late :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843564/start-condition-for-tex-equations