# start condition for TeX equations

Tags: lex

In lex, I can define the following starting condition for equations defined between `$...$`.

```
%x EQN1

\$ { BEGIN(EQN1); }
<EQN1>{
    \$ { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
    [^\$]* {} 
}
```

For equations between `$$...$$`, how can I define the anything but `$$` rule, such as in `[^\$]*`. I guess `[^\$\$]*` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't understand the way the patterns are matched, see flex [manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)

Flex always try to match longest input possible. You can understand it in way, that longer rules have higher priority.

Because "\$\$" match two characters and "." just one, the example below will work just fine.

```
%x EQN2

\$\$ { BEGIN(EQN2); }
<EQN2>{
    \$\$ { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
    . {} 
}
```

You can also replace `[^\$]* {}` with `. {}` in your example, because when rules match same size of input, the first one in lex.l has higher priority.